# How to create a bar chart with a mean line in the Dash app?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

**Hello, could someone provide a code example of how to create a bar chart with a mean line in Dash.**

I managed to create a bar chart but I cannot find out how I add a trace to an existing dcc.Graph via the callback function output.

Thank you very much.

This is an an **example** of how the chart should look:

[image]

Here are some code snippets from what I have tried:

```py
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='surprice_pct_last_month1'),
    ],style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
```

and

```py
@app.callback(
     dash.dependencies.Output('surprice_pct_last_month2', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency2', 'value')])

def update_surprise_last_month2(currency2):

    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency2]

    output = output.groupby('Event').last()
    output = output.dropna()
    output1 = output[(output.Surprise_Pct < 400) & (output.Surprise_Pct > -400)]
    output2 = output[(output.Surprise_Pct > 399) | (output.Surprise_Pct < -399)]


    output['Mean'] = output.Surprise_Pct.mean()
    output['Median'] = output.Surprise_Pct.median()
    #output2['Mean'] = output2.Surprise_Pct.mean()
    #output2['Median'] = output2.Surprise_Pct.median()

    data = []
    trace_data = go.Bar(x=list(output.index),
                        y=list(output.Surprise_Pct))
    data.append(trace_data)
    layout = {'title':'Monthly Surprises - {}'.format(currency2)}

    return {
        'data':data,
        'layout': layout
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Do you have some demo code and test data?

Comment: I used pandas to create a DataFrame that I use to format the data and dash. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

y = [random.randrange(-200,200) for _ in range(80)]
mean = sum(y) / len(y)
fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=list(range(len(y))), y=y)])
fig.add_shape(
        go.layout.Shape(
            type="line",
            x0=-.5,
            y0=mean,
            x1=len(y)-.5,
            y1=mean,
            line=dict(
                color="Orange",
                width=4,
                dash="dash",
            ),
    ))
fig.show()
```

[image: result]

PS: [This online example](https://dash.plot.ly/interactive-graphing) suggests that data is just a list of dictionaries. So, to get things working with Dash, I propose:

```
tracedata1 = go.Bar(x=x, y=y)
tracedata2 = go.layout.Shape(type="line", ...)
data.append(trace_data1)
data.append(trace_data2)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to build this in the Dash app. I changed the title to better make this clear. Thank you though!

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `trace_data = go.Bar(...)` and `trace_data.add_shape(go.layout.Shape(type="line", .....))` in your code?

Comment: Hm there is an error: Bar has no attribute add_shape. How I understand it I should add a figure to the Graph, but the output is already the dic {} so that I cannot do the usual: fig = ... and fig.add_trace.

Comment: I tweaked your suggestions a bit and it worked perfectly. What I didn't realize is, that within the data dict I can already specify the type of the graph. Somehow I thought I have to do it in the layout section. Thanks JohanC!

Answer (score 0):

Based on JohanC's suggestions I figured out how to utilize Dash and Plotly.
I didn't realize that one can simply add another dict into the data list and specify within the dict what type of graph the data should be displayed as.

```py
@app.callback(
     dash.dependencies.Output('surprice_pct_last_month1', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('currency1', 'value')])

def update_surprise_last_month1(currency1):

    output = calendar[calendar.Currency == currency1]

    output = output.groupby('Event').last()
    output = output.dropna()
    output1 = output[(output.Surprise_Pct < 400) & (output.Surprise_Pct > -400)]
    output2 = output[(output.Surprise_Pct > 399) | (output.Surprise_Pct < -399)]


    output['Mean'] = output.Surprise_Pct.mean()
    output['Median'] = output.Surprise_Pct.median()
    #output2['Mean'] = output2.Surprise_Pct.mean()
    #output2['Median'] = output2.Surprise_Pct.median()

    data = []
    trace_data = go.Bar(x=list(output.index), y=list(output.Surprise_Pct), name='Surprise in %')

    trace_data2 = {'x': output.index, 'y': output.Median, 'type': 'scatter', 'name': 'Median'}
    trace_data3 = {'x': output.index, 'y': output.Mean, 'type': 'scatter', 'name': 'Mean'}

    print(output.Median)
    print(output.Mean)

    data.append(trace_data)
    data.append(trace_data2)    
    data.append(trace_data3)

    layout = {'title':'Monthly Surprises - {}'.format(currency1)}

    return {
        'data':data,
        'layout': layout
    }
```