# Use bar chart and average line on facet grid in Plotly

Tags: plotly, facet, plotly-python

I want to plot facet grid with barcharts and average line for each facet. Example of desired result of one graph can be seen on the image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120877/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-with-a-mean-line-in-the-dash-app) but the final figure should have multiple graphs like that, each in a facet.

I have tried the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287001/how-to-overlay-two-plots-in-same-figure-in-plotly-create-pareto-chart-in-plotl), but I didn't find a way to use it with facets. I'd like to use `facet_col` option as it draws as many plots as distinct values in the column.

Ideally, I want to have these two figures displayed on one (the code below is not syntactically correct, just to give understanding).

```
px.bar(df, x='category', y='user_count',facet_col='domain', facet_col_wrap=4)
px.line(df, x='category', y='user_count_avg',facet_col='domain', facet_col_wrap=4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- you have not provided sample data, hence have generated
- concept: the number of facets in both figures are the same as they are created with same data frame (have same **domain** and *category* for xaxes and facets).  With this in mind the same axes will have been assigned by **plotly express** to both figures
- now just append lines to bars and have your required integrated figure

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "category": np.tile(list("ABCDEF"), 6),
        "domain": np.repeat([".co.uk", ".com", ".sg", ".media", ".fr", ".de"], 6),
        "user_count": np.random.randint(20, 100, 36),
    }
)
df = df.groupby("domain", as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.assign(user_count_avg=d["user_count"].mean())
)

b = px.bar(df, x="category", y="user_count", facet_col="domain", facet_col_wrap=4)
l = px.line(
    df, x="category", y="user_count_avg", facet_col="domain", facet_col_wrap=4
).update_traces(line_color="red")

b.add_traces(l.data)
```

[image]